# Multiple invocations of a static method

Tags: java, function, methods, static, jvm

my question is this:

In 3 different classes I have to execute a method that has the same procedures but different values ​​in the parameters.

- Is it okay to use a new class that contains a static function and
  change the values ​​as each call requires?
- How does JVM proceed by having several instances of a static method, 
  a "tail" of orders is generated?

The question is more in the theoretical sense of how JVM handles memory, what I'm looking for is not only saving lines but memory. I want to say that if by doing this I generate more consumption or it is worse to generate more code in each class although I would write more lines.

If there is a better way, I would appreciate it if you told me.

From already thank you very much.

Comment: I doubt it would matter. Write the code that is the cleanest, keep it simple.

Comment: I don't think a JVM will ever "combine" wholly separate methods.  If one calls another, it may be inlined, but no other optimization comes to mind.  If you truly have three methods that are the same, you should endeavor to make one method that takes different parameters.  An example of what you are trying to do would help, your question is very general.

Comment: Thanks jontro.

Hello mark space, I create a single method that can receive different values. My question is oriented to how JVM handles this.
I want to know, for example, if two different classes call the same static method of another class, this generates a kind of waiting for the one who calls after the other, establishing priorities.
And if it would act the same or worse if the code were separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty difficult to understand without some illustrative code, but to address the two explicit points:

> Is it okay to use a new class that contains a static function and change the values ​​as each call requires?

Sure, why not?

> How does JVM proceed by having several instances of a static method, a "tail" of orders is generated?

There is no such thing as 'instances of a static method'. Possibly you mean 'invocations'. If so, and if '"tail" of orders' and 'generates a kind of waiting' are intended to mean some kind of sequentialization, the answer is no: concurrent calls proceed in parallel, unless synchronization or a lock is employed.

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer I was looking for was this "concurrent calls proceed in parallel, unless synchronization or a lock is employed.".
And for this "Sure, why not?" I asked because maybe there was a sequencing and there was a better way to invoke a function.